# CRM 2011 : Creating GUID of a custom entity record to a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using a Stored procedure to genearte a SSRS report in CRM 2011 , My stored procedure is using one i/p parameter as GUID . Is it possible to run this report for a particular  Custom entity record in crm  CRM .

Thanks,
Sheen

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Better to start as a CRM report, and use the input parameter that is passed properly by MSCRM.